# Is there a reference for EF4 Fluent API syntax?

Tags: entity-framework-4, fluent, entities

I keep searching the web for examples of the new fluent API syntax in Microsoft's Entity Framework technology previews ... I come up with bits and pieces here and there.

Is there any reliable place to go to find ALL the possibilities? And maybe something that explains them a bit ("HasRequired", "WithMany", etc.)?

FYI, I am specifically trying to figure out how to define a foreign key/primary key relationship explicitly through fluent API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, unfortunately, not at this time. The current syntax is a preview and subject to change. There is no official documentation yet. There is nothing in MSDN. The best one-stop example I found is [here](http://blog.cincura.net/231783-ultimate-efv4-ctp4-code-first-full-mapping-example-using-firebird/). See also [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/14/ctp4codefirstwalkthrough.aspx) and the items linked there.

Folks on the leading edge can expect turbulence. :)

**Update:** The [API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) was just released.

Answer (score 2):

The best reference at the moment are blog posts (=> google). You can start with [ADO.NET Team blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/) where are announced new features with examples.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has more than one year old, but for those who arrive here: MSDN now has an entry on [Code First Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295844%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) with introductory examples and common tasks.